# Can I see object itself that I defined in R?

Tags: r

For example, I defined a model:

```
Model <- lm(Sales~(a + b + c, data))
```

At this point, if I input Model in R, I get a result of regression analysis.

But at here, I want to have that the object itself, in other words, I want to see `Model <- lm(Sales~(a + b + c, data))` in the result screen. Isn't there some way to do this?

Comment: print("Model<-lm(Sales~(a+b+c,data)") does that, but I'm not sure why you want to do this.

Comment: after creating the model, which you named "Model", then type summary(Model) and that will give you the results of your linear regression.

Comment: `lm` objects have a field `call` which you could get with `Model$call`. That would give you `lm(Sales~a+b+c, data)`. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Thanks. I meant "Model$call". Really thanks for help.

Comment: @astrofunkswag, please post as answer ...

Comment: @BenBolker I posted it. I wasn't clear on what the OP wanted

Comment: thanks. (I interpreted OP's last comment as saying that you had answered their question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lm` objects have a field `call` which you could get with `Model$call`

That would give you `lm(Sales~a+b+c, data)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just print it use `print("Model<-lm(Sales~(a+b+c,data)")` as dshkol suggested, or `cat("Model<-lm(Sales~(a+b+c,data)")` if you don't want quotes.

If you need to use the output in another function you can use `substitute("Model<-lm(Sales~(a+b+c,data)")`

If you need the result to be a character then you can always wrap it in `as.character(substitute("Model<-lm(Sales~(a+b+c,data)"))`.

Does that help?